# Fixed point with time dependence

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, fixed-points

If I have a growth rate of

$
\frac{dN}{dt} = (1+cos(\alpha t))r(c-N)-\mu N
$

and I used the normal method of finding a fixed point (by making the differential equal to 0) I would get

$
N = \frac{(1+\text{cos}(\alpha t))rc}{\mu+r(1+\text{cos}(\alpha t))}.
$

Which doesn't produce the fixed point. What does this value represent? and how would I find the fixed point(s) of the system?

Comment: benharmer, I think you made an algebra mistake.  If $dN/dt=0$ for all $t$, then $r(c-N)-\mu N$=0.

Comment: @irchans Sorry, I have fixed my mistake. I used the wrong formula!

Comment: After you revised your question, I think there are no fixed points if $r\neq0$ and $\mu\neq 0$.  Suppose $N(t) = d$  when $a<t<b$.  Then $N'(t)=0$ when $t\in(a,b)$.  The expression $\cos(\alpha t)$ is changing on the interval, but $N'(t)=0$ on that interval, so that implies $N(t)=c=d$.  But then $\mu N(t)$ is non-zero.  So basically, there are no fixed points if  $r\neq0$ and $\mu\neq 0$.   That's not quite a proof, but if you filled in all the details, it would be.

Comment: @irchans, sorry, I could not understand very well your comment, maybe because is my firts time on Dynamical Systems. If there exists an equilibrium $d$, so it must be s.t. $N(t)\to d$ when $a<t<b$ for an interval $(a,b)\ni d$, I could not understand why did you put $N(t)=d$ at whole interval to construct the contradiction. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi Na'omi. You are correct.  My idea does not prove that $N(t)$ does not converge to $d$ within a neighborhood of $d$.  For a formal proof, I think that you could assume that there is a fixed point $d$.  Then prove that there exists an $\epsilon>0$ s.t. $| N(t_0) - d| <\epsilon$ implies $| N(t) - d| >\epsilon$ for some $t>t_0$.  I'm not sure this works.  If I get time, I will look at it later.  

I did a numerical experiment with r=$\mu$=1/100 and c=1.  In that case $N(t)$ oscillated around N=1/2.